# PHP Deprecated: The Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::getFactoryClass symfony 2.6

Tags: php, symfony

I see an error message:

> PHP Deprecated:  The
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::getFactoryClass
>   method is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0.

when running

```
composer update
composer run-script post-update-cmd
```

on my symfony 2.7 project.

I checked 
app/bootstrap.php.cache

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

cli/php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Even though I see error_reporting() = 0 during debug, it still shows me those messages.

How to suppress Deprecated messages in Symfony 2.7?

Comment: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-7-1-released seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

At the begining of your App.php

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: Unfortunately app.php is not even an entrance point in that case. It is app/console file. And I tried to add error_reporting there.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to suppress Deprecated messages with passing error_reporting level to Debug::enable in *app/console*, as follows:

```
if ($debug) {
    Debug::enable(E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_DEPRECATED);
}
```